# Limit without hospital's rule $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{x}{\sin^3(x)})$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Calcule $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} (\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{x}{\sin^3(x)})$ without using L'Hospital

I first was trying to replace $x = \frac{\pi}{2} + u$ but I can't find a rule or eliminate anything.
After that I try using cubes:

$\frac{\sin^3(x) - x^3}{x^2\sin^3(x)} = \frac{(\sin(x)-x)(\sin^2(x)+x^2+x\sin(x))}{x^2\sin^3(x)}$ but again i couldn't find any rule or formula.

How can I solve this problem without using L'Hospital? Thank you very much in advance

Comment: If $x$ is close to $0$ then $\sin x$ is close to $x$.

Comment: $|\sin x| \leq |x|$ could be helpful.

Comment: Hinit: For $x$ near $0$, $x/\sin^3(x)$ is positive, so $1/x^2+x/\sin^3(x)\gt1/x^2$.

Comment: Is there a minus or a plus between terms? Also, can you use the series expansion of $\sin x$?

Comment: When making an attampt to solve the problem, the OP assumes that there is a minus sign between the terms.

Comment: Lesson learnt: The limit of a sum equals the sum of the limits in case the addends are convergent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{x}{\sin^3x}\right) &= \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin^3x-x^3}{x^2\sin^2x}\right) \\
&= \lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{x^3}{\sin^3x}\right)\left(\frac 1{x^2}\right)\left(\frac{\sin^3x}{x^3}-1\right) \\
&=1\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}-1\right)\left(\frac{\sin^2x}{x^2}+\frac{\sin x}{x}+1\right) \\
&=1\cdot\lim_{x\to 0}\left(\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}\right)\cdot3 \\
&=1\cdot\left(\frac {-1}6\right)\cdot3 \\
&=\frac{-1}{2}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

We know $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$, so your limit is
$$
\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1+\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^{-3}}{x^2}
$$

And it's numerator goes to 1, and denominator goes to 0.

So your limit is $\infty$(especially, positive valued.).

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the problem, and there should be a minus sign between the terms, not plus.

Comment: i'm so sorry, i made a mistake, i already corrected it. Following your solution, this would be $\frac{0}{x^2}$ right?, then i would be $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{0}{x^2} = 0 $ right?. Thanks so much